# Django form errors in loop

Tags: python, django

**forms.py**

```
def clean(self):
    for item in self.my_items:
        if item.number == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Error %s" % item.pk)
```

This code displays error only for first item(after first loop). How can I display errors for all `my_items`?

**html:**

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    {{ error }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `add_error` method.

```
self.add_error(fieldname, 'My error here')
```